# React redirecting to ? parameter while submitting request instead of Rest api

Tags: reactjs

Hitting submit from http://localhost:3000/newReport.
 i have three fields treeselectdropdown, a textbox and a number field. i am setting days in state.
 It redirect to http://localhost:3000/newReport?days=10 (if i give no of days as 10).

```
**import React from 'react';
import TestDropdownTreeSelect from './DropdownTreeSelect';
import Select from 'react-select';



class NewReport extends React.Component{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     days:null
    };
    this.getResults = this.getResults.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    this.setState({

     days: target.value
    });
  }
  getResults() {
if(this.state.days!=null || this.state.days!=0)
   alert(this.state.days);

    fetch('*********************/************/getReportData?libraryName=R1_CONTENT_en_IN')
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => {
        console.log('R4_CONTENT_en_US----------------')
        console.log(text);
        console.log('R4_CONTENT_en_US----------------')

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
      })
  }
    render(){
        return (

            <div>
              <form required>
              <div class="label">
                  <b>New Report</b>
              </div>
              <br></br>

              <div className="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="labelNameLib">
                      <b>Library</b>
                          </div></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <TestDropdownTreeSelect />

                   </div>

                </div>
              </div>


                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                    <div class="labelName">
                     <b>Author</b> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                    <div className="col-md-2">

                     {/*  <Select options={Authors}></Select> */}
                     <input type="text" ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-2"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                    <div class="labelName">
                        <b>Expiry Date in Next</b>
                        </div> </div>
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <input type="number"  required
                       title="Enter number from 1 to 365"  
                       value={ this.state.days } name="days"
                       onChange={ this.handleChange }
                       pattern="[0-9]{1,3}"  min="1" max ="365"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-1"><b>Days</b></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>

                <div>

                  <button type="submit" class="runReport" 
                  onClick={this.getResults} 
                  style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFD700', marginLeft: '15%' }}>Run Report</button>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
                </form>
              </div>   
            );
          }
        }**
```

I am not getting rest api result in console. Why it is redirecting to ?days=10.
i am using fetch for hitting rest api requests

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour with a [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). You test the example on the page, the page is reloaded. To prevent this with JavaScript you have to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Here is the snippet updated:

```
class NewReport extends React.Component{   
  getResults(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you accept my answer then if it fixed your issue? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers